# Will Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express run on Celeron 1.2GHz?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have small dedicated server (Celeron 1.2GHz, 2GB RAM, 250GB HDD) running currently on Gentoo Linux + MySQL. I'd like to migrate to Windows Server with SQL Server Express.

I know my machine is below minimum requirements (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#SSE_x64) but my question is: will it ever run? I don't mind if it will be slow. The traffic will be minimal for SQL Server (1-2 users at a time).

Comment: It won't be slow, it will be slooooooooow.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 R2 is a 64-bit-only operating system. Your processor has to be x64.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/system-requirements.aspx

Your processor seems like a 2001-era design, which would not have x64 instruction set required to operate Windows Server 2008 R2. Celeron was refreshed with 64-bit capabilities around 2005.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeron

UPDATE

As you have reported your processor model is the [Celeron 220](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=33102), it is an more modern version with the required Intel64 support. You may be able to install Windows 2008 R2 then. Notice I state *may* because the minimum speed is actually *1.4GHz*; yours is 1.2GHz. The installer might have logic to throttle the processor and halt further installation if it is too slow. However I am inclined to think the likelihood of such a blockage existing is low.

Comment: As far as I know it is 64bit. It was configured about 1 year ago (it's very low price dedicated server). So if I have 1.2GHz instead of 1.4GHz this configuration won't work at all?

Comment: Confirm your CPU model.

Answer (score 0):

See the system requirements for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express here:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/SQLServerExpress.aspx

(bottom of the page)

> Supported Operating Systems
>
> ```
> * Windows® Server 2003 Service Pack 2
> * Windows® Server 2008
> * Windows® Vista
> * Windows® Server 2008 R2
> * Windows® 7
> * Windows® Vista Service Pack 1
> * Windows® XP Service Pack 2
> * Windows® XP Service Pack 3
> ```
>
> Physical Limitations
>
> ```
> * 32-Bit Systems: Computer with Intel or compatible 1GHz or faster
>   processor (2 GHz or faster is recommended. 
>   Only a single processor is supported.)
> * 64-Bit systems: Computer with Intel or compatible 1.4 GHz or higher
>   processor (2 GHz or faster is recommended. 
>   Only a single processor is supported.)
> * Minimum of 512 MB of RAM (1 GB or more is recommended)
> * 1.9GB of free hard disk space
> ```

Comment: My server is 64bit. So if I install Windows Server 32bit despite of that, it should run ok?

Comment: Episodex, Windows Server 2008 R2 comes ONLY in 64-bit flavour.

Comment: @icelava `x86_64 Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 220 @ 1.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux` - that's from console. I reckon it's this model: [link](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=33102)

Comment: heh, comment to wrong answer post.